# Converting .obj to .dae using subprocess or concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, objects, obj, conversion, dae

I have tried quite a few ways to convert a few thousand .obj to .dae using various methods. [Concurrent futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) I assume does not work because `bpy` is not [thread safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). When I try `subprocess` it cannot seem to find Blender when it goes to execute.

I basically need just this in some multiprocessing format, but I am unsure of how to achieve it after trying multiprocessing, subprocess, and concurrent.futures.

```
CONVERT_DIR = os.getcwd()

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

def find_base_color_node(mat):
    try:
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                break

        return node.inputs["Base Color"].links[0].from_node
        
    except Exception:
        return None

def get_node_name(node):
    try:
        return node.label or node.image.name
    except Exception:
        return None

def convert_recursive(base_path):
    for entry in os.scandir(base_path):
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.obj'):
                filepath_src = entry.path
                filepath_dst = f"{os.path.splitext(filepath_src)[0]}.dae"

                print("Converting Meshes...")
                bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=filepath_src)
                mat_names = [
                    mat.name for mat in bpy.data.materials
                    if mat.name.startswith("MAT")
                ]

                for mat_name in mat_names:
                    mat = bpy.data.materials[mat_name]
                    node = find_base_color_node(mat)
                    if new_name := get_node_name(node):
                        mat.name = new_name
                bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=filepath_dst)
                bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
                bpy.ops.object.delete()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert_recursive(CONVERT_DIR)
```

Comment: I think you would be more successful using concurrency with multiple blender instances rather than trying to shoehorn multiprocessing into a single instance of blender which has already its fair share of problems with a single import / export process :)

Comment: But bpy is not thread safe, so I do not think it is possible. Blender will still wait for each one I think. It also would not know when to stop, I'll need to think of another solution.